# jQuery: click event issue(i wont remove a newly added element)

Tags: jquery, events, click

I having some issue with a click event, if a user clicks on a link it will append a box to the body, and if a user clicks on the link inside the box it should remove the box but i dont. If I append the box outside the click event it works, but this isn't what i want. I am doing something stupid i just know it but i cant seem to see what.

// inside the plugin wrapper

```
    var obj = $(this);

    obj.click(function(e){

        $(body).append('<div id="thebox"><a href="#" id="thelink">a link</a></div>');

        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#thelink').on('click',$(this),(function(e){

        $('#thebox').remove()

        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#thelink').on('click',$(this),(function(e){

        $('#thebox').remove()

        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Should look like:

```
$('body').on('click','#thelink',(function(e){

        $('#thebox').remove()

        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: @user759235 welcome, but accepting answer is best way to thanks.

Comment: yes i know...but i had to wait 11 minuts before i could click the button, but its done now ;)